# Which preposition is appropriate with "compensation"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> Could you work on this for free?

In an answer to the above question, which preposition is correct to use with the word *compensation*?

> — No, I would like to work *with compensation*.
>
> — No, I would like to work *under compensation*.
>
> — No, I would like to work *on compensation*.

Or, should we just say:

> No, I would like to be paid for my work.

Comment: Your last sentence, "I would like to be paid for my work", is best.

Comment: @StoneyB So there is no collocation we can use for an answer that includes the word compensation?

Comment: How about "No, I would like to be compensated for my work." or "No, I would like compensation for my work."

Comment: I actually think "**for** compensation" is more correct than any of your versions. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of them seem completely natural ("compensation" seems a bit formal), but in that specific context, I'd actually suggest "**for compensation**", because it mirrors the question:

> Could you work on this *for free*?
>
> No, but I can work on that *for compensation*.

or even better,

> No, but I can work on that *for pay*.

Answer (score 1):

You may also say, "I don't work for charity. How much are you going to pay me?" As for the three examples, I've found no such collocations; to say the least, they all sound odd to me.

The preposition which works with "compensation" is "for", as in "I want some compensation for the time I lost at this meeting".

Comment: IMO, some might consider _"I don't work for charity. How much are you going to pay me?"_ a little too rude. You may come off a little bit too aggressive to the listener.

Comment: Yet, every work should be payed for, unless it's charity, shouldn't it? If someone wants you to do some work and thinks that agreement on the  payment is optional, why not clear that out beforehand?

Comment: Yes, I agree. But we need not resort to harsh replies. If they find it offensive, they wouldn't even give us the work at all. Creating a good impression is always nice.